# Remove files by extension from all levels of a directory subtree without destroying the directory structure

Tags: linux, shell, glob

Using a shell script, I want to remove only text files, log files, and CSV files from the following directory structure, while leaving the directory structure intact:

```
|
|------bar/
    |
    |---file1.txt
    |---file2.txt
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1.log
    |   |---file2.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1.log
        |---image2.log
```

I am using `rm -rf /bar/*`, so I am getting the following result:

```
|------bar/
```

However, I want the following result:

```
|
|------bar/
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   
    |   
    |
    |---subdir2/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On UNIX (or on Windows using cygwin):

Old school:

```
find bar -type f -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" -print0 |
xargs -0 rm -f
```

Using GNU find (suggested by mklement0):

```
find bar -type f -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" -delete
```

Comment: find *.txt,*.csv -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
find: *.txt,*.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: Kudos for using `-print0` / `-0` for robustness, but given that the question is `linux`-tagged, why don't you just use GNU `find`'s `-delete` action?

Comment: @mklement0 Does `-delete` work for write-protected files (i.e. does it do what `rm -f` does)? The documentation is not clear.

Comment: Good question; a quick test on Ubuntu 12.04 (`find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`) tells me: _yes, it does_ (works with both write-protected files and files needing a change of ownership, assuming sufficient privileges) - ditto for FreeBSD/OSX `find`.

Comment: Thanks; +1; conversely, we now know that your `xargs` / `rm` solution actually offers one advantage over using `find`'s `-delete` action: by  omitting `rm`'s `-f` option you can _opt out_ of forced deletion.

Answer (score 0):

This command will find and remove all .log,.txt and .csv files in the bar directory:

```
find ./bar/ -type f -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" | xargs rm
```

If your files contain spaces you will need to use a slight variance on Employed Russian's solution:

```
find ./bar/ -type f -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" -print0| xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: This will end up badly if you have a files with space in their name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `bash 4+`:

```
(shopt -s globstar nullglob; cd bar && rm **/*.txt **/*.log **/*.csv)
```

- shell option `globstar` turns on support for matching files across directory-hierarchy levels with `**`.
- shell option `nullglob` makes globs that match NO files return an *empty string* rather than passing globs through unmodified, which typically results in errors).
- The whole command is run in a subshell (due to enclosure in `(...)` so as to localize the effect of changing shell options.